# Find the number of subsets of {1, 2, . . . , n} with an odd number of elements.

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of subsets of {1, 2, . . . , n} with an odd number of elements.

I am looking at an example where they are asking for an even number of sets. Do the number of even and odd sets have to be equal? I am confused :/

Comment: Do you count $\emptyset$ as an even subset?

Comment: Is $n$ even or odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is odd then you have $$\binom {n}{1} +\binom {n}{3}+...+\binom {n}{n}  $$  and this is equal to $$\binom {n}{n-1} +\binom {n}{n-3}+...+\binom {n}{0}  $$

Thus the number of odd sets and the even set are equal so each has $2^{n-1}$ elements.

Foe an even $n$ the odd sets are   $$\binom {n}{1} +\binom {n}{3}+...+\binom {n}{n-1}  $$  and the number of even sets is  $$\binom {n}{0} +\binom {n}{2}+...+\binom {n}{n}  $$

and the two numbers are equal again so we have $2^{n-1}$ again.

Answer (score 2):

If n=0, the answer is 0, since there is only one subset of the empty set (itself), and that has even size.

If n>0, then there are $2^{n-1}$ ways to choose a subset $S$ of $\{1,2,...,n-1\}$. For each of them, exactly one of $S, S \cup\{n\}$ has odd size.

Thus, there are $2^{n-1}$ such sets.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n\ge 1$. We pair up each subset of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ that doesn't include the element $1$ with the corresponding subset that does include the element $1$.  This will uniquely pair up the subsets.  And one subset of each pair will have an even number of elements and one will have an odd number of elements.  Hence the number of even subsets is equal to the number of odd subsets.

For instance if $n=3$, we have these pairings:

$\emptyset\leftrightarrow\{1\}$

$\{2\}\leftrightarrow \{1,2\}$

$\{3\}\leftrightarrow \{1,3\}$

$\{2,3\}\leftrightarrow \{1,2,3\}$

Answer (score -1):

Say $S_n=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. First assume $n$ is odd. Then $E\subset S_n$ has an odd number of elements if and only if $S_n\setminus E$ has an even number of elements. So the number of odd subsets is the same as the number of even subsets, hence $2^n/2=2^{n-1}$.

Now suppose $n$ is even and $E\subset S_n$. Let $$F=E\cap S_{n-1}.$$ For $E$ to be odd there are two possibilities: $F$ is even and $n\in E$ or $F$ is odd and $n\notin E$. So the number of odd subsets of $S_n$ is the same as the number of subsets of $S_{n-1}$, again $2^{n-1}$.

Comment: What's the problem?